# Hebrew SMS in Android

Tags: java, android, unicode, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap to create plugin aimed at sending SMS. Below is the function I use to do it.

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
  // Activity currentActivity = (Activity)this.ctx;
  SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(cordova.getContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
  manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
}
```

When the variable "message" contains English, everything works fine. But if the 
message is in Hebrew, I receive an error.

See below  input in Hebrew

סך הלכל מוזמן 2 פריטים 
סלט פיצוצ בסרי שווה ל 10.3 כמות  1
סלט שרימפס שווה ל 8.15 כמות  2
 סך הכל חשבון 26.6 שקלים

Below is a class that holds the text description. I suspect that the problem is problem with the unicode, but I do not know how to fix it.

Please help.

```
public class MenuEntry {
  public String getPid() {
    return pid;
  }
  public void setPid(String pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
  }
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
  public double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }
  public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }
  public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
  }
  public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
  }
  public MenuEntry() {
    super();
    this.pid = "";
  }
  public String GetPriceAndDescription(int unit) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(this.getTitle());
    result.append(" שווה ל ");
    result.append(this.getPrice());
    result.append(" כמות  ");
    result.append(unit);
    result.append("\n");
    return result.toString();
  }
  public String GetPriceAndDescription() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(this.getTitle());
    result.append(" שווה ל ");
    result.append(this.getPrice());
    result.append("\n");
    return result.toString();
  }
  public MenuEntry(String pid, String title, String description, double price, String categoryName) {
    super();
    this.pid = pid;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
  }
  private String pid;
  private String title;
  private String description;
  private double price;
  private String categoryName;
}
```

See below the definition of the manifest file, to see the target version.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: "I receive an error." is as useful information as my current advice for you: "then fix it".

Comment: What error are you getting? What Android version are you testing on?

Comment: For Hebrew inside Java Strings to be correct both editor and javac compiler have to operate in the same encoding (`javac -encoding utf`) or use unicode escapes `\u05d0`  (aleph). (Unlikely you erred there.)

Comment: Is that possible in programming way to convert it to unicode. I saw that in Eclipse , there is a menu that convert text into Unicode, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
The problem was with the "SmsManager" class. When the message is too long ,
the class throws exception, but without description.

So I needed to use other method "sendMultipartTextMessage" of the SmsManager class.

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        ArrayList<String> parts = manager.divideMessage(message);

        manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);

}
```